# groovy string formatting

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to test a SQL query for groovy/grails. Going over why is the SQL insert is not working, I'm trying to print out that query line. Surprising, not even that work, so I'm investigating about the string formatting in groovy. If someone has a clue about it please let me know.

```
println  """INSERT INTO iu (version, path, uuid, name, description,
                            sourceversionfrom, sourceversionexto,
                            targetversionfrom, targetversionexto,
                            phase, directive, classname, methodname,
                            functionalarea_id, upgradepath_id, date_created,
                            last_updated, mark4delete, firstAvailable_id,
                            lastAvailable_id, uniqueid_id, elementcreateddate,
                            purpose, implementationdetails, userimpact)
              VALUES ( ${this.version}, ${this.path}, ${this.uuid}, ${this.name},
                       ${this.description}, ${this.sourceversionfrom},
                       ${this.sourceversionexto}, ${this.targetversionfrom},
                       ${this.targetversionexto}, ${this.phase}, ${this.directive},
                       ${this.classname}, ${this.methodname}, $functionalarea_id,
                       $upgradepath_id, NOW(), NOW(), 0, ${this.projID},
                       ${this.projID}, ${this.uniqueid_id},
                       ${this.getElementCreatedDate()}, ${this.purpose},
                       ${this.implementationDetails}, ${this.userImpact} )"""
```

the program halts and stands by after that line

Comment: What do you mean by _"the program halts and stands by"_?  It crashes?  It prints nothing out and hangs?  BTW:  The code you posted looks fine to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your query string.  The program may be hanging on retrieving one of the properties (`version`, `path`, `uuid`, etc.) through a getter, or on the call to `getElementCreatedDate`.

To see what your program is doing when it hangs, you can generate a thread dump.  When groovy is being run interactively in a terminal or console window, send a QUIT signal or type <kbd>ctrl-\</kbd> on Linux or OS X, or type <kbd>ctrl-break</kbd> on Windows.  Look for the `"main"` thread and scan down the stack trace until you reach your own code.

Comment: The function ${this.getElementCreatedDate()} is the trouble source. I have isolated the problem, it is producing a NULL pointer that is causing the program to stand still ...